# ImageResizer library for android

Tags: java, android, image, resize, image-resizing

I'm developing an android application that needs to pick an image from gallery or camera and put it on MainActivity. Also, i want the user to can resize and move this image in MainActivity.

Is there any library to do that?

Comment: Use Picasso for this, it very easy and helpful

Comment: Use BitmapFactory.Options for resize images.@Mohsen Morshedi

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use for image download,resizing and Scaling

[Glide](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-image-resizing-scaling) Or [Picasso](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit)

Comment: actually i want the user that use the app to resize and scale the image